# Loginscript using a txt file for authentification

Tags: php, nosql

I want to make a simple login script with NoSQL by using a text file.
For the moment the user credentials are stored within the code and I am not able to store it outside.

My code:

```
<?php
$error = "";
if(isset($_POST['username'],$_POST['password'])){

    $user = array(
                    "user" => "demo",
                    "pass"=>"demo"          
            );
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];
    if($username == $user['user'] && $pass == $user['pass']){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['simple_login'] = $username;
        header("Location: home.php");
        exit();
    }else{
        $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Invalid Login</div>';
    }
}
?>
```

Any advice is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: So you want to move the username and password from the php file that 'nobody' but you can open and place them in a text file that anyone can open (with the correct url)?

Comment: yeah, i want to move it to a textfile - security wont be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**since OP has said security is not an issue, this code is OK for him/her to use.

But this code should not be used on a live webpage as it has numerous security flaws.**

You can read a text tile using file_get_contents().
In my example I use `,` as a separator between username and password, I can therefore explode with `,` to separate them.
I use array_combine() to create the same array as you have with associative named keys.
Enough talk...

```
<?php
$error = ""; 
if (isset($_POST['username'],$_POST['password'])){
    $arr = array("user", "pass");
    $file_data = file_get_contents("path_and_filename.txt");

    $user = array_combine($arr, explode(",", $file_data));
    /*$user = array(
                     "user" => "demo",
                     "pass"=>"demo"          
            );*/
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];
    if($username == $user['user'] && $pass == $user['pass']){
       session_start();
        $_SESSION['simple_login'] = $username;
        header("Location: home.php");
        exit();
    }else{
        $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Invalid Login</div>';
    }
}
?>
```

Example textfile for above code to work.

```
demo,demo
```

..

```
//username,password
```

Notice no space between `,` and words.